# I want to get object attributes from suds reply with Python but it contains 'return'

Tags: python, suds, reply, cucm

I have this suds reply

```
(reply){
    return = 
      (return){
         lineGroup[] = 
            (LLineGroup){
               _uuid = "{4065AB99-B8AB-6B97-C930-AC3816346346}"
               name = "Failover"
            },
            (LLineGroup){
               _uuid = "{1EF78256-030D-31F6-B70F-60DF93143646}"
               name = "Empfang"
            },
      }
 }
```

As I understand it, to get the name attribute you would use something like this:

```
print result.return.LLineGroup.name
```

but It contains the word 'return' and Python says its a Syntax Error

What can I do?

Actually I need someting like this:

```
for item in result['return'].lineGroup:
    print item.name
```

Thank you John!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print result['return'].LLineGroup.name
```

This is a common technique in other libraries and languages, and while I'm not a Suds expert, a quick reading of the code makes it seem like this will work.